# Why do the numbers in my output string get subtracted?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to keep a record table to see how many times a player has lost to another player, but in the record column the numbers are getting subtracted.

My Ouput:

```
Name          Won    Lost    Record
-----------------------------------
Player 1       4      3        1

Player 2       3      4       -1
```

Desired Output:

```
Name          Won    Lost    Record
-----------------------------------
Player 1       4      3        4-3

Player 2       3      4        3-4
```

Here is the code I have that is giving me my output:

```
            string columnBeat1 = "[BEAT " + tbl1_p2Txt.Text.ToUpper() + "]";
            string columnBeat2 = "[BEAT " + tbl1_p1Txt.Text.ToUpper() + "]";
            string columnLost1 = "[LOST TO " + tbl1_p2Txt.Text.ToUpper() + "]";
            string columnLost2 = "[LOST TO " + tbl1_p1Txt.Text.ToUpper() + "]";
            string columnRecordBeat = "[RECORD VS " + tbl1_p2Txt.Text.ToUpper() + "]";
            string columnRecordLost = "[RECORD VS " + tbl1_p1Txt.Text.ToUpper() + "]";

            SqlCommand cmdBeat = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.[RECORD] SET " + columnBeat1 + " = " + columnBeat1 + " + 1 " + " WHERE [NAME] = @Name", con);
            SqlCommand cmdLost = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.[RECORD] SET " + columnLost2 + " = " + columnLost2 + " + 1 " + " WHERE [NAME] = @Name", con);
            SqlCommand cmdRecordBeat = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.[RECORD] SET " + columnRecordBeat + " = " + columnBeat1 + '-' + columnLost1 + " WHERE [NAME] = @Name", con);
            SqlCommand cmdRecordLost = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.[RECORD] SET " + columnRecordLost + " = " + columnBeat2 + '-' + columnLost2 + " WHERE [NAME] = @Name", con);

            cmdBeat.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdLost.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdRecordBeat.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdRecordLost.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            con.Open();
            cmdBeat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbl1_p1Txt.Text);
            cmdBeat.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdLost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbl1_p2Txt.Text);
            cmdLost.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdRecordBeat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbl1_p1Txt.Text);
            cmdRecordBeat.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdRecordLost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbl1_p2Txt.Text);
            cmdRecordLost.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Think about what ColX=ColY-ColZ means.

Comment: @doubleYou I understand what it means and can see why it is subtracting the values, but how can I fix this so that it will show the hyphen instead of subtracting the numbers?

Comment: What data type is `record` in the DB?  `AddWithValue` is not advised, but the `record` could/should be a parameter also.

Comment: @Plutonix record is a varchar and could you explain why AddWithValue is not advised? I am new to working with sql and databases I am trying to self-teach myself for this project I am working on.

Comment: Open Google.  Type "Whats wrong with AddWithValue".  Study the first hit.  *Thats* how you do research and learn.  Sometimes all you learn are new terms to Google.  Baby steps

Comment: @Plutonix I know I could google it I was just wondering if you were able to give a quick explanation since you were the one that pointed it out to me

Comment: There is *quick* and there is *comprehensive*.  Quick is because you are making the DB Provider guess at the data type.  The article explains why that can be a Bad Thing.  Being self-taught you should immerse yourself in details and not just the basics.  A little bit of knowledge is a dangerous thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FrankX has stated in his answer, the problem is that you're dealing with numbers, not strings. Putting a minus between two numbers usually means you want to subtract - SQL is not an exception here.

Let's first consider how we would do this in C#.

```
int winCount = GetWinCount();   // get the value 4 from somewhere, e.g. the database
int lossCount = GetLostCount(); // get the value 3 from somewhere, e.g. the database

string resultColumnName = "Result";
string winsColumnName = "Wins";     // we don't actually need this
string lossesColumnName = "Losses"; // we don't actually need this

// what we want is a string like this:
// Result='4-3'

string query = "UPDATE ... SET " + resultColumnName + " = '" + winCount + "-" + lossCount + "' WHERE ..."
```

Now, C# actually hides the interesting part from us: winCount and lossCount are `int`s, but we need `string`s. This happens behind the scenes. The `+` in the line that builds the query silently converted those two values to the strings "4" and "3" respectively.

If we don't want to do this in C#, we need to tell the database to create a string-value of the form 'X-Y' where X and Y are integers that are converted to strings. I haven't done this kind of thing in SQL in a while, so I cannot tell you the exact syntax, but look for `CONVERT` and `CONCAT` functions.

In C#, where you construct the query string, you then need to use the `winsColumnName`, `lossesColumnName` in combination with those functions. From C#'s point of view, the function names are just strings, of course. It will look similar to this:

```
string query = "... " + resultColumnName + "=CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, " + winsColumnName + "), '-', CONVERT(VARCHAR, " + lossesColumnName + ")) ..."
```

Comment: The CONCAT and CONVERT function in SQL worked perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because the input isnt string. use the single quote or set it with sqlparameter

Comment: When I use the single quote without any double quotes it does not recognize my variable columnBeat1 or columnLost1 and if I use the single quotes with the double my output becomes the [columnX]-[columnY] with no numerical values

Comment: "UPDATE dbo.[RECORD] SET " + columnRecordBeat + " = **'**" + columnBeat1 + '-' + columnLost1 + "**'** WHERE [NAME] = @Name"  (try to spot the bold single quotes - don't know how to make them stand out better)

Comment: @doubleYou Yes when I put in the bold single quotes you have my output becomes columnBeat1-columnLost1

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. You need to replace columnBeat1 and columnLost1 with their actual values. Don't know how to do this conversion in SQL right now.

Comment: @doubleYou How am I supposed to convert them? I'm getting the actual values from the table and storing them in columnBeat1 and columnLost1

Answer (score 0):

This is for `SQL Server`. Try something like this:

```
        SqlCommand cmdRecordBeat = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.[RECORD] SET " + columnRecordBeat + " = " + CAST(columnBeat1 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(columnLost1 AS VARCHAR) + " WHERE [NAME] = @Name", con);
        SqlCommand cmdRecordLost = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.[RECORD] SET " + columnRecordLost + " = " + CAST(columnBeat2 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(columnLost2 AS VARCHAR) + " WHERE [NAME] = @Name", con);
```

Hope it helps you.